# Neovim suggestion line highlight

Tags: neovim

I recently updated from neovim v7 to v10 (NVIM v0.10.0-dev-1613+g585eeacb2)

Right after the update, I started having an issue when opening suggestion dropdown - selected line is not highlighted. Same issue appears when having any popup prompts with options to choose from.

[image: screenshot]

I tried:

- Re-installing neovim (same version)
- Upgrading and Updating Coc and Vim Plug extensions
- Changing and completely removing color schemes

Here's my [health check result](https://ctxt.io/2/AABQvwdyEQ), doesn't seem to have anything related

Does anyone have suggestions of what it may be?